# Float operations using double

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

I have a function which takes two strings(floating point) , operation and floating point bit-width:

```
EvaluateFloat(const string &str1, const string &str2, enum operation/*add,subtract, multiply,div*/, unsigned int bit-width, string &output)
```

input str1 and str2 could be float(32 bit) or double (64 bit).

Is it fine If store the inputs in double and perform double operation irrespective of bit-width and depending upon bit-width typecast it to float if it was 32 bit.
e.g

```
double num1 = atof(str1);
double num2 = atof(str2);
double result = num1 operation num2; //! operation will resolved using switch
if(32 == bit-width)
{
 float f_result = result;
 output = std::to_string(f_result);
}
else
{
 output = std::to_string(result);
}
```

Can I assume safely f_result will be exactly same if I had performed operation using float type for float operations i.e.

```
float f_num1 = num1;
float f_num2 = num2;
float f_result = f_num1 operation f_num2
```

PS:

1. We assume there won;t be any cascaded operation i.e. out = a + b + c
   instead it will transformed to: temp = a +b  out = temp + c
2. I'm not concerned by inf and nan values.
3. I'm trying to code redundancy otherwise I have two do same operation
   twice once for float and other for double

Comment: A `double` gives no less precision than `float`, and the set of values a `float` can represent is a strict subset of the set of values a `double` can represent. So, there is no potential loss of precision converting from `float` to `double`, but there is converting back. You may get a different result if you do the operations purely with `float`s. Those cases aren't a a sign that you've lost precision by doing things with `double` - it means you're achieving more precision than you would by doing the operation purely on `float`s, but less than doing everything with `double`s.

Comment: Thanks Peter. May be I framed my question incorrectly, our is a equivalence checker tool so we need to match whatever the result is as per language semantics.

Comment: U gave us too less information, to see why u want to do, what u do. I for my part, really dont understand why there are stings, when u operate on floats. Never the less. U will most certainly get different result, when your operations are all double and return a float. Compared to operations on float and return a float. Not only in precision, but also the result will be different, because float is less precise than double and therefor the operations vary. U can't compare the results and get a match. U have to implement a compare function with a delta, then u will create matches.

Comment: @skratchi.at our is a equivalence checker tool so we need to match whatever the result is as per language semantics.

Comment: Are you sure `str1` and `str2` have exact `float` representations? E.g., 'simple' numbers like 0.1 have not. And at your 'PS 3': Why not write a template method?

Comment: Yes, they have exact float . Yeah , I could template but I was trying to avoid it if its not required. Thanks for you help

Comment: "Yes, they have exact float " implies `FLT_TRUE_MIN` has a string representation like "0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125".  Are you sure the string representation you use are _exactly_ the value of a `float`?

Comment: input str1 and str2 could be float(32 bit) or double (64 bit). Perhaps you should clarify what you mean? It seems a bit misleading because you only consider float as input.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not specify which formats are used for `float` or `double`. If IEEE-754 binary32 and binary64 are used, then double-rounding errors do not occur for `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, or `sqrt`. Given `float x` and `float y`, the following hold (`float` arithmetic on the left, `double` on the right):

- `x+y` = `(float) ((double) x + (double) y)`.
- `x-y` = `(float) ((double) x - (double) y)`.
- `x*y` = `(float) ((double) x * (double) y)`.
- `x/y` = `(float) ((double) x / (double) y)`.
- `sqrt(x)` = `(float) sqrt((double) x)`.

This is per the dissertation [*A Rigorous Framework for Fully Supporting the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic in High-Level Programming Languages*](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/csweb/Research/Theses/figueroa_sam.pdf) by Samuel A. Figueroa del Cid, January 2000, New York University. Essentially, `double` has so many digits (bits) beyond `float` that the rounding to `double` never conceals the information needed to round correctly to `float` for results of these operations. (This cannot hold for operations in general; it depends on properties of these operations.) On page 57, Figueroa del Cid gives a table showing that, if the `float` format has *p* bits, then, to avoid double rounding errors, `double` must have 2*p*+1 bits for addition or subtraction, 2*p* for multiplication and division, and 2*p*+2 for `sqrt`. Since binary32 has 24 bits in the significand and `double` has 53, these are satisfied. (See the paper for details. There are some caveats, such as that *p* must be at least 2 or 4 for the various operations.)

Comment: Does this hold for `pow(x, y)` as well?

Comment: @LMD: That is not proven in Figueroa’s dissertation, and I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

According to standards floating point operations on `double` is equivalent to doing the operation in infinite precision. If we convert it to `float` we have now rounded it twice. In general this is not equivalent to just rounding to a `float` in the first place. For example. 0.47 rounds to 0.5 which rounds to 1, but 0.47 rounds directly to 0. As mentioned by chtz, multiplication of two floats should always be exactly some double (using IEEE math where `double` has more than twice the precision of `float`), so when we cast to a `float` we have still only lost precision once and so the result should be the same. Likewise addition and subtraction should not be a problem.

Division cannot be exactly represented in a double (not even 1/3), so we may think there is a problem with division.  However I have run the sample code over night, trying over 3 trillion cases and have not found any case where  running the original divide as a `double` gives a different answer.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        long i=0;
        while (1) {
                float x = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
                float y = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
                float  f = x / y;
                double d = (double)x / (double)y;
                if(++i % 10000000 == 0) { std::cout << i << "\t" << x << "," << y << std::endl; }
                if ((float(d) !=  f)) {
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                        std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;
                        std::cout << std::hex << *(int*)&x << "," << std::hex << *(int*)&y << std::endl;
                        std::cout << float(d) - f << std::endl;
                        return 1;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi gmatht,
One difference here is you have kept input as double vs float whereas in my case input will float is just that we storing it in the double.

I modified your code a bit and its running infinitely:

Comment: int main() {
    double epsilon=1.0;
    int i=0;
    while (1) {
            epsilon=epsilon/2.0;
            float f = (float)(1 + epsilon) ;
            float g =  (float)(1 + epsilon);
            float h = f * g;

            double d = f ;
            double e = g;
            double x = d * e;

            std::cout << ++i << "," << epsilon << std::endl;
            std::cout << x << "," << float(x) << "," << h << std::endl;
            std::cout << float(x) - h << std::endl;
            if ((float(x) !=  h)) {
                    return 1;
            }
    }
}

Comment: Somehow on my machine its keep on running.Can you please share the output before it stopped. Is it a nan value?

Comment: @PGupta doh sorry, I was looking at my new code, but running the old code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the product of two `float` is always exactly representable as `double` (assuming standard IEEE 754 and only finite factors). You are essentially multiplying two 24 bit numbers (which gives at most 48 significant bits) and store them into a 53 bit number. But you can likely find examples with division where your test would hit.

Comment: @gmatht Yes, but I don't think you can find two floats `x`, `y` where `double(x)*double(y)` needs rounding.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought that since we have 29 bits more precision in a double we would have a roughly 2^-29 chance that the division wasn't exactly equal, but I have checked 726380000000 cases without finding any such cases.